# Value of type’StorageReference’has no member ‘listAll’

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to get a list of all items in a given directory “images/profilePics” in my iOS app By using the listAll() API for StorageReference, but getting the error “Value of type ‘StorageReference’ has no member ‘listAll’. I am not sure of what could be causing this error. An example of how I have implemented this API will can be found below, thanks.

```
    Let storage = Storage.storage(),
    ref =    storage.reference().child(“images/profilePics”)

    ref.listAll{ (result, error) in
       if let error = error {
       }
       for prefix in result.prefixes {
       //do  something
       }
       for item in results.items {
       //do something
       }
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably using an old version of the FirebaseStorage library.  According to the [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios), [the list API was added in version 6.4.0](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios#storage_6).  The most recent version is 6.23.0.  Make sure you're up to date.

Comment: Thanks, Doug. I will update my project and keep you posted.

Comment: Thanks, Doug, Updating FirebaseStorage fixed my problem.